How do I add text or a message below the featured image in wordpress?
How do I add text or a message below the featured image in WordPress?
Text appears in pages and articles.
https://easyupload.io/afvm9s

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
